# void main() { if(sizeof(int) > -1) printf("true"); else printf("false"); ;

Tags: c

```
void main()
{
    if(sizeof(int) > -1)
        printf("true");
    else
        printf("false");    
}
```

I expected the output to be true but it is false. Can anybody please explain me the reason for the output.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`sizeof(int)` is of type `size_t`, which is an unsigned integer type. So in the expression `if(sizeof(int) > -1)`, `-1` is converted to an unsigned integer, which is very big.

BTW, use `int main` instead of the non-standard `void main`.

Answer (score 7):

sizeof(int) returns size_t which is as `unsigned int`.

Usual arithmetic conversions are **implicitly** performed for common type.

```
int --> unsigned int --> long --> unsigned long --> long long --> unsigned long long --> float --> double --> long double
```

`int` value(-1) is converted to `unsigned int` as part of implicit conversion.

`-1` will be represented as `0xFFFF` in `16 bit machine(for example)`.

So expression becomes,

```
if(sizeof(int) > -1 ) ==> if(2 > 0xFFFF)
```

And `false` is printed. I suggest to try `if((int)sizeof(int) > -1 )` for proper result.

Comment: Downvoting because this answer fails to explain why `0xFFFF` would compare greater than `2` in this case when it compares less in `2 > -1`.

Comment: @user2357112 updated reason.

Answer (score 1):

The data type of value provided by `sizeof` is `size_t` which is (in most machines) an `unsigned int/long`, therefore, when you compare it with `-1`, `-1` is type promoted to `unsigned` which then becomes `0xFFF..` , which is the largest value that datatype can hold, therefore your comparison fails.