# Why is this statement false? Can someone explain

Tags: c

I got here an actually "easy" C code Block but my compiler gives me an other result as expected.

```
int a;
int c;
unsigned int b;

a = b = 10;
c = -1;

if(a+b > c)
   printf("True\n");
else
   printf("False\n");
```

In my opinion a + b = 20 and its always more than -1 but why is it false?

Comment: `b` is unsigned. I think `a+b` then becomes an `unsigned` operation, and similarly the comparison is `unsigned`. You're comparing 20 with 65535.

Comment: other duplicates: [Comparison operation on unsigned and signed integers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2084949/995714), [Why is a negative int greater than unsigned int? (duplicate)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13600991/995714), [How is it possible for 0 <= -1 to return true? (duplicate)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52309235/995714)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to compare the result of `a+b` and `c` then they need to be the same type.

Because `b` is unsigned then the result of `a + b` is also unsigned. This means that either that result, or `c`, must be converted. The conversion will be that `c` is converted (through [*promotion*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions)) to an `unsigned int` and then `-1` becomes a very large value (`4294967295` on most systems). `20 > 4294967295` is false.

Comment: so i guess what i posted is an integer promotion then ?

Answer (score 1):

The unsigned value of c is the largest value an integer can hold. Where as a signed value of c is -1. But if you print C as hexadecimal you receive `0xffffffff` so it strictly comes to representation and consistency. -1 Can be treated as signed if you want it to be and unsigned if you don't want it to be. Try this code.

```
    int x = 0xffffffff;
    printf("%d",x);
```

It will print -1. So when comparing types you also have to be consistent of do you want the comparison and representation to be signed or unsigned?
Your code can be fixed with a simple cast.

```
    int a;
    int c;
    unsigned int b;

    a = b = 10;
    c = -1;

    if((int)(a+b) > c)
       printf("True\n");
    else
       printf("False\n");
```