# Why is "sizeof(double) > -1" false?

Tags: c, output, double, sizeof

```
int main()
{
    if(sizeof(double) > -1)
        printf("M");
    else
        printf("m");
    return 0;
}
```

I expected the output to be M but it is m. Can anybody please explain me the reason for the output?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20853451/void-main-ifsizeofint-1-printftrue-else-printffalse

Answer (score 3):

That's because `sizeof` returns a `size_t` value, that is, a unsigned integer type, so, -1 will overflow.

Comment: In `sizeof(double) > -1`, −1 is converted to `size_t`. This is defined to wrap and not to overflow.